# Remove background texture on photograph while still maintaining shading photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

[image]

I'm wanting to remove the background scrape effect texture on this mockup. This is an editable psd but the box and background are a flattened jpg. I was wondering if it would be easier to cut and paste the box onto a different background entirely? I want to recreated the shading and I don't have any experience with creating 3D mockups in photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to mask the box, remove it completely the shadow, and add a new one.

1. Mask the box > Make it a new layer. Get rid of the background.
2. Draw some shapes
3. Blend them together
4. Blur them a bit

[image]

I did that in vectors but you could try something else in Ps.

[image]

Forgive my lazy masking